# Populate a Multi-column Combobox with a 2D array on Access

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, combobox

I tried to follow this method:

```
ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 2

Dim Films(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Films(1, 1) = "Lord of the Rings"
Films(2, 1) = "Speed"
Films(3, 1) = "Star Wars"
Films(4, 1) = "The Godfather"
Films(5, 1) = "Pulp Fiction"

Films(1, 2) = "Adventure"
Films(2, 2) = "Action"
Films(3, 2) = "Sci-Fi"
Films(4, 2) = "Crime"
Films(5, 2) = "Drama"

ComboBox1.List = Films
```

[source](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/multicolumn-combo-box.html)

But the ***.List*** property does not work on Access. Any ideas ?

Comment: Loop through array and use AddItem to build combobox ValueList. Or build a table of these values and use it as RowSource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As June7 said, use the **ComboBox.AddItem()** method in a loop. For your purposes, the ComboBox must not be bound to a data source: It's *Row Source Type* property should be set to "Value List". To add a multi-column string to a ComboBox row, use a semicolon to delimit the the columns. For example:

```
ComboBox1.AddItem (Films(1, 1) & ";" & Films(1, 2))
```

or

```
Dim rowStr As String
rowStr = Films(1, 1) & ";" & Films(1, 2)
ComboBox1.AddItem (rowStr)
```

AddItem() automatically appends the row to the end of the ComboBox's list, if you do not specify a row index parameter. For more info, see [ComboBox.AddItem method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.additem?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaac10.chm11476)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) at Office Dev Center.

Screenshot: [VBA Demonstration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz7Rw.png)

Answer (score 2):

A "Form" in Access is not the same kind of element/object as a "UserForm" is in Excel where your "source" link points to (https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/multicolumn-combo-box.html).

In Access it would be a good idea to get the information into your Combo Box (or List Box) from either a table or a query. You can of course code it with VBA, but then you might find yourself adding/editing a hole lot of VBA here and there, as in Access it all goes more naturally by using SQL and the database engine.

This is a larger topic, but basically you should probably have different tables for "Films" and for "Categories"

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

Then you should define the relationships since most likely there are different amount of films in your database than there are categories. Saying that we would like to avoid a situation that you would have to add another movie, let's say "Die hard" into your movie list. That would probably fall into the category "Action". In the database we do not want to repeat ourselves. Just we will, by ID, refer to categoryID by it's value.

[image]

So, having done that you need to create a form in Access. Create maybe a query that will get the values for you:

[image]

After this you can define the source for the combo e.g. by using wizard:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So this way you can maintain each of the lists separately in their own tables.

Here is the query that got created:

[image]

- On the Data tab you can decide which bound column to use relative to datasource.
- On the Format tab you can adjust the widths of the columns in your combobox. Use 0 length to hide a column.

This way no VBA code is needed.

If needed it is also possible to create or edit the queries with VBA but that is another story.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer helped a lot !

Comment: Perhaps you mean Categories (with a C instead of G).

Comment: Yes June7. I did mean Categories :), sorry all.